# Adding an AND (x OR y) to an existing where clause of a view doesn't work

Tags: sql-server

I'm currently trying to compile a view over several databases using the query editor of SSMS 18.9.2. Everything is working fine except for the `WHERE` clause. This is what the auto generated code looks like:

That's what I had when I started to add another clause:

```
WHERE (
  autoline_basis.dbo.autoline_newst_basis.modelcode LIKE '[A-Z]%'
)
AND
(
  lux_web_sam.chl.checklists.creationdate > CONVERT(datetime, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 102)
)
AND
(
  lux_web_sam.dbo.ordernumbers.fk_checklist IS NOT NULL
)
AND
(
  lux_web_sam.chl.checklists.fk_usedvehicletype IS NULL
)
```

I need another clause which ensures that, in addition to the above (AND) either one of two values is NOT NULL -> AND (x or y):

```
AND (Autoline_Basis.dbo.Autoline_NEWST_Basis.OrderDate IS NOT NULL) OR (Autoline_Basis.dbo.Autoline_NEWST_Basis.V55Received IS NOT NULL)
```

Based on my intuition, I would write it like that:

```
WHERE (
  autoline_basis.dbo.autoline_newst_basis.modelcode LIKE '[A-Z]%'
)
AND
(
  lux_web_sam.chl.checklists.creationdate > CONVERT(datetime, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 102)
)
AND
(
  lux_web_sam.dbo.ordernumbers.fk_checklist IS NOT NULL
)
AND
(
  lux_web_sam.chl.checklists.fk_usedvehicletype IS NULL
)
AND
(
  (
    autoline_basis.dbo.autoline_newst_basis.orderdate IS NOT NULL
  )
  OR
  (
    autoline_basis.dbo.autoline_newst_basis.v55received IS NOT NULL
  )
)
```

With the double bracket around the last OR statement to make sure that the first block must be true and only one of the second block. However, when I hit the save button, the double brackets are removed. to a single bracket around every table name:

```
WHERE (
  autoline_basis.dbo.autoline_newst_basis.modelcode LIKE '[A-Z]%'
)
AND
(
  lux_web_sam.chl.checklists.creationdate > CONVERT(datetime, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 102)
)
AND
(
  lux_web_sam.dbo.ordernumbers.fk_checklist IS NOT NULL
)
AND
(
  lux_web_sam.chl.checklists.fk_usedvehicletype IS NULL
)
AND
(
  autoline_basis.dbo.autoline_newst_basis.orderdate IS NOT NULL
)
OR
(
  autoline_basis.dbo.autoline_newst_basis.v55received IS NOT NULL
)
```

That gives me some entities with an Orderdate prior to 2021-01-01 because the last clause  `(Autoline_Basis.dbo.Autoline_NEWST_Basis.V55Received IS NOT NULL)` is true. Obviously, the statement is wrong. How can I add that last AND (x OR y) to my clause to have the proper statement?

EDIT:

When I write it like that:

```
WHERE (
  autoline_basis.dbo.autoline_newst_basis.modelcode LIKE '[A-Z]%'
)
AND
(
  lux_web_sam.chl.checklists.creationdate > CONVERT(datetime, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 102)
)
AND
(
  lux_web_sam.dbo.ordernumbers.fk_checklist IS NOT NULL
)
AND
(
  lux_web_sam.chl.checklists.fk_usedvehicletype IS NULL
)
AND
(
  autoline_basis.dbo.autoline_newst_basis.orderdate IS NOT NULL
OR 
  autoline_basis.dbo.autoline_newst_basis.v55received IS NOT NULL
)
```

It's being translated to this code (which at a second glance seems syntactically correct, but includes some redundancy):

```
WHERE (
  autoline_basis.dbo.autoline_newst_basis.modelcode LIKE '[A-Z]%'
)
AND
(
  lux_web_sam.chl.checklists.creationdate > CONVERT(datetime, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 102)
)
AND
(
  lux_web_sam.dbo.ordernumbers.fk_checklist IS NOT NULL
)
AND
(
  lux_web_sam.chl.checklists.fk_usedvehicletype IS NULL
)
AND
(
  autoline_basis.dbo.autoline_newst_basis.orderdate IS NOT NULL
)
OR
(
  autoline_basis.dbo.autoline_newst_basis.modelcode LIKE '[A-Z]%'
)
AND
(
  lux_web_sam.chl.checklists.creationdate > CONVERT(datetime, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 102)
)
AND
(
  lux_web_sam.dbo.ordernumbers.fk_checklist IS NOT NULL
)
AND
(
  lux_web_sam.chl.checklists.fk_usedvehicletype IS NULL
)
AND
(
  autoline_basis.dbo.autoline_newst_basis.v55received IS NOT NULL
)
```

Edit 2: I followed the advice of Charlieface and translated my script to a separate `CREATE OR ALTER VIEW` script so that I could control the `WHERE` logic myself.

Comment: Your intuition is right, `OR` has lower priority than `AND` in SQL parser, hence your condition is not parsed the way you want it. Add parentheses around the `OR`s that go inside `AND`, i.e. `AND (Autoline_Basis.dbo.Autoline_NEWST_Basis.OrderDate IS NOT NULL OR Autoline_Basis.dbo.Autoline_NEWST_Basis.V55Received IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: There's really no sane reason to be using the designers in SSMS. They're full of unaddressed issues that haven't been touched in years.

Comment: I noticed that. It's just horrible. There was a time one when I added something and it messed up the complete script, resulting in nonsense.

Comment: "when I hit the save button" if you're using the designer, don't. Just write the code in a query window. Side note: learn how to use table aliases, they make code more readable. And style `102` for dates is `yyyy.mm.dd`, instead use an unambiguous date format such as `YYYYMMDD` or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`